# How to use a dynamic port forwarding tunnel via a bastion/jump server using PuTTY without WinSCP

Tags: port-forwarding, putty, tunnel, ssh-tunnel, winscp

I have a requirement to connect to a remote JMX server via an SSH bastion/jump server.
I can successfully use a Linux ssh client to achieve the desired result and also can use a PuTTY session dynamically launched via WinSCP (on Windows) to open a **dynamic** (important!) port-forwarding tunnel but I'm really struggling to remove this WinSCP dependency on Windows.

The (working) steps on Linux are simply as follows:

1. First open a new tunnel with `ssh -fN -D $LOCAL_PORT user@host` (where host is configured at ~/.ssh/config to use bastion/jump server with private key)
2. Run client program (which is **jconsole** to connect to a remote JMX server) `./jconsole -J-DsocksProxyHost=localhost -J-DsocksProxyPort=$LOCAL_PORT service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:$TARGET_PORT/jmxrmi -J-DsocksNonProxyHosts=`

The slightly more convoluted steps on Windows using WinSCP and PuTTY are:

1. Open WinSCP and create a new connection to the target host using the advanced settings to tunnel through the bastion/jump host (works with either private key or Pageant)
2. Use the built-in WinSCP option to launch a new PuTTY session (through the tunnel)
3. Edit the settings of the new PuTTY session to create a local dynamic forwarding port
4. Use jconsole to open the connection with `jconsole -J-DsocksProxyHost=localhost -J-DsocksProxyPort=$TUNNELPORT service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:$TARGETPORT/jmxrmi -J-DsocksNonProxyHosts=`

What I'm hoping to achieve is remove any dependency on WinSCP and just use PuTTY to create/use the port forwarding tunnel. I've tried editing the 'SSH Remote Command' option to add -D option and editing settings after successfully opening a remote tunnelled session manually to no avail. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong please?

[EDIT] This question was moved from Stack Overflow to Super User as suggested by Martin Prikryl

Comment: I assume you need something like this: [PuTTY configuration equivalent to OpenSSH ProxyCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28926612/850848).

Comment: That looks fairly close, except you will probably want to do it through `-proxycmd` rather than PuTTY GUI.